# Is it possible to use different volume levels for different players (AVAudio Player and MPMusicPlayer) while they are playing simultaneously?

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

I need to set different volume levels for different players using AVAudio and MPMusic Players, I am playing both players but I do not know how to set different different volumes levels.

Thank you,
Madan Mohan

Comment: I've answered a similar question recently. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867112/independent-volume-control-of-avaudioplayer-and-mpmusicplayercontroller-in-ios-ap/6871811#6871811

Answer (score -1):

Say your avaudioplayer is named theAudio. To control that volume, say [theAudio.volume =//volume here]; Do the same for mpmusicplayercontroller.